# Using Django in Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I am trying to use Django in Eclipse, but I have no idea how to import Django in Pydev project lists. The 'New Project' just has 'Pydev projec'.

Some help please
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can import from file system and point tou your django project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the latest versions of both Pydev and Django. If you've installed Django properly, then it should be available under the 'Pydev' tab of 'New Project' as 'Pydev Django Project.' Otherwise, you can right-click on your project folder -> Pydev -> 'Set as Django project'.

Comment: Well, I think Django is installed properly, I run Django development server in terminal.
And I right click on the Pydev project in Eclipse, but there isn't any 'Set as Django'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the Eclipse version problem like you said (I doubt it though). Another way you might want to try is to just create a new Pydev Project. Under the project name textbox, there is a section called project contents. Uncheck the "Use Default" and browse to your pydev directory and see what happen.

Maybe after this, you can try what rohanbk has mentioned to 'Set as Django project'.

Comment: I selected 'user/lib/eclipse/plugins/Pydev1.2' but it haven't got me 'Set as Django project'

Comment: @Tao's method actually works. Remember to not add a 'src' folder and set it up later.

Answer (score 0):

A Django project can be imported as a PyDev project - after all, a Django project **is** a Python project. As rohanbk [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578367/using-django-in-eclipse/3578398#3578398) you can convert it to a "Django Project" after successfully importing.

Comment: Right, but when I want to import my project from 'file> import> existing project' and i select my existing project folder, it gives me no available projects to select from. Isn't it because I may have not installed the right Eclipse (SDK 3.2.2)?

Comment: @Ehsan: Do you already have a project that you can import or are you trying to create one?

Comment: Actually I've created one using terminal Django development server and coded according to Django tutorial. But Eclipse doesn't recognize that!

Comment: Well I was successful to import using 'import file system', but I suppose this way may not give me all the Pydev functionality for Django?